# what could be the reason for the JDO key retrieved to be different from the one persisted?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing, jdo, data-persistence

In my google app engine application, i persisted jdo below for sometime,

```
package com.acti.JDO;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;

@PersistenceCapable
public class Subscription {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key ;

public Key getKey() {
    return key;
}

public void setKey(Key key) {
    this.key = key;
}

@Persistent
private String email;

@Persistent
private String clientID;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getClientID() {
    return clientID;
}

public void setClientID(String clientID) {
    this.clientID = clientID;
}
}
```

At later point i wanted to change clientID to clientId,

```
@Persistent
private String clientId;

public String getClientId() {
    return clientId;
}

public void setClientID(String clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
}
```

and made the changes accordingly and deleted the previous jdo entities and started persisting jdo with new 'clientId' key. Though I can see only clientId in Datastore, when i am retrieving the subscription jdos, the key i am getting is 'ClientID'

The code i am trying to get the jdo entities is below

```
   public ArrayList<Subscription> getSubscriptionJDOs(String    queryParam)
   {
    ArrayList<Subscription> subscriptionJDOList = null;
    PersistenceManager          persistentManager  = null;
    Query                                   query  = null;

    try
    {
        subscriptionJDOList   = new ArrayList<Subscription>();  
        persistentManager     = JdoUtil.get().getPersistenceManager();
        query                 = persistentManager.newQuery(Subscription.class, queryParam);

        subscriptionJDOList.addAll((List<Subscription>) query.execute());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.info("Subscription Exception while getting the the subscription JDOs ::"+ex.getMessage());
    }

return subscriptionJDOList;
}
```

But the jdos i am trying to get has key clientID, instead of clientId. I tried to kill app engine instance and tried out again. Still not resolved. anyone know why this happening.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: your classes on the server are not changed then. The log tells you what is being persisted

Comment: Thanks for reply Neil, But as per the logs clientId is the key that gets persisted

Comment: as per the logs what gets retrieved?! Only you can see it, and if you don't share it then you're unlikely to get any meaningful reply. Ps "clientId" is a FIELD, not a Key. The Key is "key"